# ImportError: No module named modules.TestModule

Tags: python, web.py

I have been stuck in this issue for a long time, my project structure goes like this,

[image]

```
import web
import sys
sys.path.append("...")
import modules.TestModule as TM    
urls = (
    '/testmethod(.*)', 'TestMethod'
)    
app = web.application(urls, globals())   
class TestMethod(web.storage):
    def GET(self, r):    
        return TM.get_func(web.input().string)    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When I execute the TestService.py it says "ImportError: No module named modules.TestModule Python"

This is a sample made to test the [`module`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9jhr9xjjauaos8q/DiginQ.rar?dl=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the entry point for your program? Usually the entry point for a program will be at the root of the project. Since it is at the root, all the modules within the root will be importable.
But in your case entry point itself is a level inside the root level.

The best way should be have a loader file (main.py) at root level and rest can be in packages. The other non-recommended way is to append root directory path in sys.path before importing any package.

Add below code before you import your package.

```
import os, sys
currDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
rootDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(currDir, '..'))
if rootDir not in sys.path: # add parent dir to paths
    sys.path.append(rootDir)
```

I have modified yut testscript.py code as below. Please try it out.

```
import web
import sys
import os, sys
    currDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    rootDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(currDir, '..'))
    if rootDir not in sys.path: # add parent dir to paths
        sys.path.append(rootDir)

import modules.TestModule as TM    
urls = (
    '/testmethod(.*)', 'TestMethod'
)    
app = web.application(urls, globals())   
class TestMethod(web.storage):
    def GET(self, r):    
        return TM.get_func(web.input().string)    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: can you modify the attchment and add it

Comment: Sorry to ask should i  add a main.py outside those 2 folders and try?

Comment: you can add the above code in your TestService.py, in case you want to keep all your scripts in a separate directory.

Comment: import modules.TestModule as TM
ImportError: No module named modules.TestModule

Comment: how did you excecute the script?

Comment: I have PyDev installed for Eclipse and I run directly from there. I tried running it from CMD and it works too.

Comment: ok this how i executed , is there anything wrong?  C:\Python27\DiginQ\scripts\TestService>python TestService.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98877/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-jitendra-sanghani).

Comment: @Sajeetharan change to this `rootDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(currDir, '../..'))`

Answer (score 1):

If the directory 'DiginQ' is on your python sys.path, I believe your import statement should work fine.

There are many ways to get the directory 'DiginQ' on your python path.

Maybe the easiest (but not the best) is to add a statement like this before you import modules.Testmodule:

```
import sys
sys.path.extend([r'C:\Python27\DiginQ'])
```

Based on your post it looks like the path is C:\Python27\DiginQ but if that's not correct just use the right path.

If you google how to set python path you will find many hits. Most important thing is your path has to include the directory above the directory with the package you are attempting to import. In your case, that means DiginQ.